# Как найти самую удаленную вершину от данной?

Tags: python, c++

Есть задача

```
Дано неориентированное невзвешенное дерево. Требуется найти самую удаленную вершину от данной.

Входные данные
В первой строке дано число n — количество вершин дерева и число k — номер вершины, для которой нужно найти самую удаленную от нее ( 1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 100 ). Далее в n строках дана матрица смежности дерева.

Выходные данные
Выведите номер самой удаленной вершины от данной. Если таких вершин несколько, выведите наименьший номер.

Примечание
Если для вершины k самая удаленная — она сама, то выведите k

Примеры
входные данные
4 2
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
выходные данные
4
```

Я понял, что нужно делать поиск в глубину, но как именно это реализовать не знаю. Если будет код, будет лучше всего, если нет, то хотя бы направление решения

Comment: *Я понял, что нужно делать поиск в глубину* Волновой алгоритм получше будет для этой задачи.

Comment: А что это? Я про такой впервые слышу

Comment: Если вы поняли что нужно писать поиск в глубину, [то почему не напишите код?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode)

Comment: На самом деле, любой обход, начинающийся в вершине k подойдет. Если вы желаете использовать дфс, то заведите массив глубин вершин и для каждой вершины запишите ее глубину как глубину ее предка + 1, а для самой вершины K инициализируйте глубину нулем